# Freeing triple pointer causes double free, but only when freeing 3rd level? pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm using triple pointer as 3D array and freeing after allocation is causing doublefree("free(): double free detected in tcache2"), but only when freeing third dimension.

```
void foo(...){

char ***a=malloc(sizeof(char **)*num);
  for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    a[i]=malloc(sizeof(char *)*6);

    for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
      a[i][j]=malloc(sizeof(char)*20)
    }
  }
 
  foo(...);  // Recursion

  for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
      free(a[i][j]);  //=>> Cause of the double free
    }
    free(a[i]);
  }
  free(a);
}
```

If I annotate "free(a[i][j]);", double free does not occur.
Am I doing something wrong?

I've tried

free(a[i][j]);
filestat[i][j]=NULL;

,but this did not solve the problem.

My guess is that there is something wrong in recursion or triple pointer declaration,
although I can't see why it only happens to 3rd level pointers.

Comment: Obligatory joke: https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: This program is fine once I added the missing `;`. https://godbolt.org/z/Gh85e7YMo So I would assume the cause of the error is in the code you haven't shown. Work on a [mcve]. It's likely as you trim things you'll find the culprit.

Comment: What do you mean by "annotate"?

Comment: Have you run your program through valgrind or compiled it with an address sanitizer?

Comment: BTW, how deep is that recursion?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for showing that freeing itself wasn't a problem. I'll make the minimal reproducible example for other future questions.

Comment: Protip. Don't allocate 2d or 3d arrays like that. Just make one big allocation for the whole array.

Comment: A wild guess is that someone is assigning one pointer to another, instead of copying the chars.

Comment: Make your life easier and use a pointer to the whole array. Simply do `char (*a)[6][20]=malloc(num * sizeof *a)`. Call `free(a)` at the end.

Comment: For example, with the memory allocated as `char (*a)[6][20] = malloc(num * sizeof *a);`, you could declare `foo()` as `void foo(unsigned num, char arr[][6][20], ...)`. You could also use *variable length array* declarations like `void foo(unsigned num, unsigned nstr, char arr[][nstr][20], ...)` or `void (unsigned num, unsigned nstr, unsigned size, char arr[][nstr][size], ...)` for greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help others help you.
Please provide something we can at least compile.

**As manipulating multiple allocations and deallocations is a frequent disaster for `C` starters I will left down a few arguments and code on this subject, including a way to create and destroy a 3D vector of `C` strings, a `char** **` thing. It may be a long post since I will be cutting and pasting, so no **TL;DR**. Just ignore it if it gets boring.**

This version of your code can at least be compiled:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void foo(size_t num)
{
    char*** a = malloc(sizeof(char**) * num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 6);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
        }
    }

    foo(num);  // Recursion

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            free(a[i][j]);  //=>> Cause of the double free
        }
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}
```

I added `num` as an argument of `foo()`, since `num` was another missing piece in the provided code.

Note that this code makes little sense, since even the compiler will tell us in this warning

```
    'foo': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
```

#### back to the array

`C` has no 2D or xD arrays like `FORTRAN`, just arrays. Arrays are just base (address) and size, and elements are fetched as base + offset, the offset being determined by the indexes. But we can have arrays of arrays, arrays of arrays of arrays and so on.

**An array is a contiguous area of memory.**

Data is placed in memory by row, so in `char array[2][3]` data is placed in memory as `array[0]` followed by `array[1]`. And `array[0]` is `char[3]`

The size of the array in memory is the product of the *dimensions* by the size of each element.

To locate element [x,y,z...] we can use the common formula
[image: converting index to address]

as in page 53 of  [Data Structures Using C, from Tenembaum and others](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131997467)

This is the operation the compiler does to locate an array element from its indexes and the array start address.

If you write `getters` and `setters` for the `struct` you can allocated the whole data in a block, and use `(x,y,z)` instead of `[x][y][z]`.

#### about the indexes

Every `C` program has an implicit array in `main`, the `argv` one, built by the OS as the program is loaded. The prototype for `main` is

```
    int main ( int argc, char*argv[] )
```

And `argv` is `char*[]`, an array of pointers to char. `argv` is often declared as `char**`, and in the next lines I will try to show some differences.

#### a first example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int  main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char array[2][3] =
    {
        [0] = {1, 2, 3},
        [1] = {4, 5, 6}
    };
    printf("array address is: 0x%p\n", array);
    return 0;
};
```

This program has 2 arrays: `argv` and `array`. At one run, compiled in 32 bits memory model, we got

```
array address is: 0x0056F8E4
```

and looking into memory at run time we see

```
0x0056F8E4  01 02 03 04 05 06 cc cc cc cc cc cc 36 8b 45  ......ÌÌÌÌÌÌ6.E
0x0056F8F3  15 14 f9 56 00 e3 20 9e 00 01 00 00 00 c8 5f  ..ùV.ã ž.....È_
0x0056F902  7b 00 f0 e2 7b 00 01 00 00 00 c8 5f 7b 00 f0  {.ðâ{.....È_{.ð
```

To confirm that the data is placed by row...

#### The "`array`" in the code is not even an array

```
    char*** a = malloc(sizeof(char**) * num);
```

Note that today all pointers have the same size, so `char**` is the same as `char********` or `void*` in the expression above.

`a` is the data here. But:

- `a` is not an array. It is just a pointer. `a` is `char***`

  - if `a` is `char***` then

    - `*a` is `char**`
    - `**a`is `char*`
    - `***a` is, of course, a char

This is `C`.

#### is the array in code really `char***`?

```
    char*** a = malloc(sizeof(char**) * num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 6);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
        }
    }
```

As we see here the inner *dimensions* are fixed, `6` and `20`. If it is the case in your code we can ask `malloc()` for a single array, and declare it as in this example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t d1           = 10;
    char(*array)[6][20] = malloc(d1 * sizeof(char[6][20]));
    array[9][5][19]    = '@';
    printf("last element in array is: '%c' [should be '@']\n", (array[9])[5][19]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
};
```

That prints as expected

```
last element in array is: '@' [should be '@']
```

Many people prefer to `typedef` the inner thing as in

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char Inner[6][20];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t d1    = 10;
    Inner* array = malloc(d1 * sizeof(Inner));
    array[9][5][19]   = '@';
    printf(
        "last element in array is: '%c' [should be '@']\n",
        (array[9])[5][19]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
};
```

For the same effect.

#### back to `main`: the need of `argc`

It is time to compare

```
    int  main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

with

```
    char*** array;
```

In `main` we have always `argc` to tell the number of parameters passed to the program.
In your code we have nothing. `a` seems to be `a[num][6][20]` but we can not be sure. This is the kind of thing that makes life of a `C` programmer miserable.

A **csv** file is in general represented by a `char** **` thing. An **Excel workbook** can be seen as a `char** ** **`, a  sinister 6-star no-joke thing. But we need to know the inner dimensions or nothing useful can be done with it. And this is the important miss in your code

**I will show an example now using your code.**

#### the generic way: *encapsulation* Example

Borrowing the `RAII` concept from `C++` we can write sort of an *object* `Array` as

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t    d1;
    size_t    d2;
    size_t    d3;
    char** ** arr;
} Thing_3D;
```

I added an `*` here because I want something easier to read in a generic example, so I will use a 3D array of strings. Strings as a null-terminated `char*` in `C` so there is another `*` but there are 3 dimensions only.

And the usual functions:

```
Thing_3D* so_create(size_t, size_t, size_t);
Thing_3D* so_destroy(Thing_3D*);
int       so_identify(Thing_3D*);
int       so_show(Thing_3D*, const char*);
```

As a constructor, a destructor, a `toSring()` method to display the contents, and `so_identify()` that creates a value of `xyz` to `array[x][y][z]` in order to be easyly identified in the output.

#### `main.c` for  a test

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 4) return -1;
    size_t    d1  = atoi(argv[1]);
    size_t    d2  = atoi(argv[2]);
    size_t    d3  = atoi(argv[3]);
    Thing_3D* one = so_create(d1, d2, d3);
    so_identify(one);
    so_show(one, "initial test");

    // test: printf last element
    printf("last element is \"%s\"\n",
        one->arr[one->d1 - 1][one->d2 - 1][one->d3 - 1] );

    one = so_destroy(one);
    return 0;
};
```

This minimal test just:

- creates an array of this `Thing_3D`
- *number* the elements as its indexes creating strings with the values
- prints the whole thing
- prints the last string to test the indexes
- destroy everything

So if this program is `p` we can run `p` on the command line and see like:

```
SO> p 1 2 2
    Creating array of 1x2x2 strings
    ***** array of 1x2x2 strings created

initial test    [1,2,2]:

  Array[0]
   000   001
   010   011

last element is "011"

SO> p 2 4 5
    Creating array of 2x4x5 strings
    ***** array of 2x4x5 strings created

initial test    [2,4,5]:

  Array[0]
   000   001   002   003   004
   010   011   012   013   014
   020   021   022   023   024
   030   031   032   033   034

  Array[1]
   100   101   102   103   104
   110   111   112   113   114
   120   121   122   123   124
   130   131   132   133   134

last element is "134"

SO>
```

### The complete code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t    d1;
    size_t    d2;
    size_t    d3;
    char** ** arr;
} Thing_3D;

Thing_3D* so_create(size_t, size_t, size_t);
Thing_3D* so_destroy(Thing_3D*);
int       so_identify(Thing_3D*);
int       so_show(Thing_3D*, const char*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 4) return -1;
    size_t    d1  = atoi(argv[1]);
    size_t    d2  = atoi(argv[2]);
    size_t    d3  = atoi(argv[3]);
    Thing_3D* one = so_create(d1, d2, d3);
    so_identify(one);
    so_show(one, "initial test");
    // test: printf last element
    printf("last element is \"%s\"\n",
        one->arr[one->d1 - 1][one->d2 - 1][one->d3 - 1] );

    one = so_destroy(one);
    return 0;
};

Thing_3D* so_create(size_t d1, size_t d2, size_t d3)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "    Creating array of %zdx%zdx%zd strings\n", d1,
        d2, d3);
    Thing_3D* new = malloc(sizeof(Thing_3D));
    new->d1       = d1;
    new->d2       = d2;
    new->d3       = d3;
    // this is just a demo: limit to 10x10x10
    d1 = d1 > 10 ? 10 : d1;
    d2 = d2 > 10 ? 10 : d2;
    d3 = d3 > 10 ? 10 : d3;
    // arr is d1
    new->arr = malloc(d1 * sizeof(char*));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d1; i += 1)
    {  // d1
        new->arr[i] = malloc(d2 * sizeof(char*));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < d2; j += 1)
        {  // d2
            new->arr[i][j] = malloc(d3 * sizeof(char*));
            for (size_t k = 0; k < d3; k += 1)
            {  // d3
                new->arr[i][j][k] = NULL;
            }
        }
    };
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "    ***** array of %zdx%zdx%zd strings "
        "created\n\n",
        d1, d2, d3);
    return new;
};

Thing_3D* so_destroy(Thing_3D* to_go)
{
    if (to_go == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < to_go->d1; i += 1)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < to_go->d2; j += 1)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < to_go->d3; k += 1)
            {
                free(to_go->arr[i][j][k]);
            }
            free(to_go->arr[i][j]);
        }
        free(to_go->arr[i]);
    }
    free(to_go->arr);
    free(to_go);
    return NULL;
}

int so_identify(Thing_3D* array)
{
    if (array == NULL) return -1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array->d1; i += 1)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < array->d2; j += 1)
            for (size_t k = 0; k < array->d3; k += 1)
            {
                array->arr[i][j][k]    = malloc(4);
                array->arr[i][j][k][0] = '0' + (char)i;
                array->arr[i][j][k][1] = '0' + (char)j;
                array->arr[i][j][k][2] = '0' + (char)k;
                array->arr[i][j][k][3] = 0;
            }
    return 0;
}

int so_show(Thing_3D* array, const char* msg)
{
    if (array == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "    [%zd,%zd,%zd]:\n\n", array->d1, array->d2,
        array->d3);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array->d1; i += 1)
    {
        printf("  Array[%zd]\n", i);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < array->d2; j += 1)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < array->d3; k += 1)
                printf("%6s", array->arr[i][j][k]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In general the `char** **` thing would change to a named thing, so this could work for any `struct` as long as the user provides methods to work with the elements, e.g. like `qsort` does waiting for a `compare` function.

The dimensions are all limited to 10. I did almost no testing ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As someone replied in the question itself, it wasn't a problem of free(). I was going to find the cause and write it here, so this does not go unsolved(or was it better to delete the post? ). It was due to assigning one of 3rd level pointers to a string literal, then trying free() on it. 
Apologies for not writing the minimal reproducible examples. As you can see, I'm fairly new to programming and thought it was about the triple pointer structure. I will be sure to write minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: please consider the things I wrote about, like encapsulation, and the distinction on use of  `[]` and pointers in the example I wrote for you. I believe it can be helpful in future projects. Maybe you should not delete the post, since complete examples like this one are good to have in a searchable base as SO.